# ASP.NET MVC - What is the benefit of using Url.RouteUrl or Url.Action versus just using the URL directly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the benefit of using Url.RouteUrl or Url.Action versus just using the URL directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your routing configuration, by using Url.RouteUrl or Url.Action your generated Url's will update along with your routing configuration.

I find the real benefit comes when tied together with [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC).  Then I have strongly typed access to my Action routes, so if my controller's change the compiler alerts me if any of my Url's need to change as well.

Comment: wow, I can't believe that I've been working with ASP.NET MVC for some time and haven't seen T4MVC yet! It looks amazing - thank you for the link. :)

Comment: quick question: what is `AlwaysKeepTemplateDirty` in T4MVC?

Comment: It makes visual studio treat the file as though it is always modified.  You can then configure T4 to run whenever the file is saved.  The result is that every time you build it will force a save and that will force regeneration of the templates, so that you don't have to remember to manually run it every time you modify a controller or view.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to set up custom routing rules to create so-called "pretty" (or SEO-friendly) URLs. If you ever change one of those URLs, you don't want to have to go through your entire application and change it every time you link to that action. On the other hand, if you use `Url.Action`, it will change automatically.

Comment: Just curious, in what situation does the routing has to be changed?

Comment: any time you want to change what url maps to a particular controller & action.